# How to include the replaced string in the replacement in Eclipse?

Tags: regex, eclipse, string

I am using the following regex to find strings of type

```
${a-z.a-z}
```

where the `.a-z` part is optional

Here's the regex I am using -

```
\$\{[A-Za-z]+\.*[A-Z][a-z]*\}
```

This will match strings like

```
${users}
${user.firstName}
```

I wanted the above matched strings to be replaced with the following corresponding replacements

```
<c:out value="${users}"/>
<c:out value="${user.firstName}"/>
```

How to do that in Eclipse?

Note, I can write a script to replace all such occurrences, but I do NOT want to replace all occurrences, but only certain ones by looking at them manually (therefore I want to do this through an editor).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this using groups -

Find : `(\$\{([A-Za-z]+)\.*[A-Z][a-z]*\})`

Replace With: `<c:out value="$1"/>`

Comment: FWIW I think `(\$\{[A-Z.a-z]+\})` would also work as a simpler regex